# FastAPI - ENUM type models not populated

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, fastapi, pydantic

Below is my fastAPI code

```
from typing import Optional, Set

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl, Field
from enum import Enum

app = FastAPI()


class Status(Enum):
    RECEIVED = 'RECEIVED'
    CREATED = 'CREATED'
    CREATE_ERROR = 'CREATE_ERROR'


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None
    tags: Set[str] = []
    status: Status = None


@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(item_id: int, item: Item):
    results = {"item_id": item_id, "item": item}
    return results
```

Below is the swagger doc generated. The Status is not shown. I am new to pydantic and i am not sure on how to show status in the docs

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

create the **`Status`** class by inheriting from both **`str`** and **`Enum`**

```
class Status(str, Enum):
    RECEIVED = 'RECEIVED'
    CREATED = 'CREATED'
    CREATE_ERROR = 'CREATE_ERROR'
```

**References**

1. [Working with Python enumerations--(FastAPI doc)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#working-with-python-enumerations)
2. [[BUG] docs don't show nested enum attribute for body--(Issue #329)](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/329)

Comment: I am using this example but I get 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: How can we add Enum options via code script? I would like to fetch the options from DB using Python

Comment: You can create an `Enum` on the fly using `CustomEnum = Enum("CustomEnum", custom_enum_values)` (where `custom_enum_values` is a `Dict[str,str]`) and then just use the `CustomEnum` type in the `BaseModel`: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/13